# Understanding この場合〜なんだろうけど

Tags: grammar

> 迷宮都市{オラリオ}はこの魔石製品を他の地域、他の国に輸出することで莫大な利益を上げていると聞く。**この場合、迷宮都市{オラリオ}っていうよりギルドなんだろうけど。**

I don't understand the second sentence. Is it actually a complete sentence? Also what does なんだろうけど express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「この場合{ばあい}、迷宮都市{オラリオ}っていうよりギルドなんだろうだけど。」

Yes, it is a complete sentence with an ***unmentioned*** grammatical subject like 「それ」, which would refer to the "agent" who makes the profits discussed in the preceding sentence.

In the preceding sentence, it states that it is オラリオ.  In the next sentence, however, it states that it might be more appropriate to say that it is the Guild rather than オラリオ that actually makes the profits.

「なん**だろう**けど」 expresses the inference that the speaker is making.  It implies that what he is saying might not prove 100% accurate.

***"In this case, it would likely be the Guild rather than オラリオ itself (that actually makes those profits)."***